# How to combine two QML files?

Tags: qgis, combine, qml

I am making a plugin. I have two QML files for the same layer and column. I want the plugin to combine the two existing files into a new QML file and then I will select which one symbol for each value I want.

The problem is, I don't know how to combine two QML files into new one. Any help?

Comment: Do you need to combine at all? If the net result is one file with one set of values.  Perhaps you could provide some XML to show the two input QML files and the structure of the final XML file to show what you want to achieve.

Comment: As far as combining XML files go, you could look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921642/merging-xml-files-using-pythons-elementtree

Answer (score 1):

i'm not a programmer, but you can try to combine qml file with Notepad++ (or any text editor) because they are based on XML language.
Idem for qlr and qgs extension.

Comment: I know I can do it manually but I want it to be automatic - it should be a function in plugin.

Comment: you could use some kind of xml library to copy nodes from one tree to the other. Standard Modul xml has ElementTree for example.